# How to add custom padding-right to tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

I want a larger value for padding right than tailwind currently offers (pr-96 which is around 24rem) I’d like something around 40rem for my project.

Following documentation, I tried, but I cannot run npm run build without an error.

```
// tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      padding: {
       xxl: 'padding-right: 40rem',
      }
    }
  }
’’’

Error:the xx class does not exist, but xx does. 
If I remove the code I added above, error goes away.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the property `padding-right` in your creation of the `xxl` utility only the value and unit, this line:

`xxl: 'padding-right: 40rem'`

should be:

`xxl: '40rem'`

This will give you an xxl size of 40rem for all padding classes `p-xxl`, `pr-xxl`, `pl-xxl`, etc...

However, you should only use padding as a direct child of theme when you want to replace all padding utilities. If you wanted to just add this size to the existing padding sizes you should use `extend` inside `theme` like this:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        padding: {
          xxl: '40rem'
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```